# Line breaks are not preserved following @brief and similar Doxygen keywords in the VS Code hover info with the Cpptools extension

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

How do I correctly apply line breaks in a documentation comment so the effects will be displayed appropriately in the hover info widget (mouse hover)? I'm currently not looking to generate any HTML or page documents.

C/C++ Extension Version: `v1.15.4`

Screenshots:

[image] [image]

In the first screenshot (the one on the left), all whitespaces are treated as a single space. The second screenshot takes into account the implicit newline as long as no `@` keywords are used.

I've tried using multiple `@brief` lines and tried explicitly adding `\n` characters but to no avail.

Code:

```
/**
    @brief 
        Function # 1.
        Newline not working.
*/
void foo(int) {}

int main()
{
    foo(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A functions brief documentation is really supposed to be a *brief* and *one-line* description. The documentation you claim is "working" is probably using the first line for the "brief" documentation, and the second line is the detailed documentation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But it still doesn't work when I exclude the use of the `@brief` keyword but have other documentation (like `@return` or `@param`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue. See [New lines are removed from docstrings if prefixed by "@brief" Doxygen style #10039](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/10039). This issue ticket in the Cpptools VS Code extension is blocked by changes in the software powering its server side: [Avoid converting newlines into spaces in Doxygen "brief" comments](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Avoid-converting-newlines-into-spaces-in/10178887), which have been in the backlog since October 2022. Thumbs-up and subscribe/follow those issue tickets if you're interested in their progress.

Note for your reference / learning purposes: I found the issue ticket by googling "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues comment newline`" and exploring the search results and their linked issue tickets.